# Id returned by UserManager is different from Id in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**BACKGROUND**

I'm working on a .Net Core API project to drive a community-driven lyrics website. So users can submit artists & lyrics. Each artist has many lyrics (classic one-to-many).

For authentication & authorization, I am using JWT tokens.

**CODE**

On my Lyrics Controller, I have a `[HttpPost]` method for the creation of a lyric. Here's the code:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("{artistSlug}/lyrics")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLyric(string artistSlug, [FromBody] LyricCreateDto newLyricCreateDto)
{
  if (newLyricCreateDto == null) return BadRequest();
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
  var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
  var lyricReadDto = await _lyricsService.AddNewLyric(user.Id.ToString(), artistSlug, newLyricCreateDto);
  if (lyricReadDto == null) return NotFound();
  return CreatedAtRoute("GetLyric", new {artistSlug, lyricSlug = lyricReadDto.Slug}, lyricReadDto);
}
```

In my `Startup.cs` I have the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DatabaseDataSeeder databaseDataSeeder)
{
  loggerFactory.AddConsole();

  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
  {
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidIssuer = _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
      ValidAudience = _config["Tokens:Audience"],
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"])),
      ValidateLifetime = true
    }
  });
  app.UseMvc();
  databaseDataSeeder.Seed().Wait();
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The User returned by `var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);` has an Id (of type `int`) that does not match the Id of the user in the `dbo.AspNetUsers` table. Plus the Id column in the table `dbo.AspNetUsers` is of type `Guid`.

I'm not sure how this can be! Here's a screenshot:

[image: user in code]

And here's a query against `dbo.AspNetUsers` in SQL Management Studio:

[image: user in database]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking at the result of an async method, in other words a `Task<>`, which has an `Id` property that is not related in any way to your user. You need to `await` the method call:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: Nice, you beat me by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You are not awaiting the result of the Task so you are not actually debugging / looking at the `User` but the `Task` object. Add the `await` keyword.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: Reciprocation :)